# problem setting up cron

Tags: ubuntu, cron

Explaining how i did it .

I am on ubuntu 10 server

```
 > sudo crontab -e
```

Typed

```
 > 01 *  * * *   php5 /var/jobs/testcron.php
```

And saved

```
 >  /tmp/crontab.t53yKk/crontab
```

It suppose to run every single minute but it is not running .

What i did wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

01 *  * * *  will run every first minute of each hour. Use * * * * * to run it each minute.

Comment: Thanks, it worked !! , one more little help. How to type when want to run every 5 mins ?

Comment: Use */5 * * * *

Comment: you are a STAR ;) .